# How Convert Capturing video to NsData?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I using camera to capturing video

```
url = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F5A89447-0720-4956-BD83-EEB541EE69AC/tmp/capture-T0x146e04ad0.tmp.TnQgmW/capturedvideo.MOV"
```

And I can't use `dataWithContentsOfFile` it give me nil all the time.

```
_videourl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {


 NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"capturedvideo" ofType:@"MOV"];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];


NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[_videourl absoluteString]];    
 NSData *videoData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_videourl];
```

Both `FileData` and `VideoData` is null and `videoData2` is only one have value

My question is how use `dataWithContentsOfURL` with temp url from camera not from the gallery ?

Comment: Replace `absoluteString` with `path`. That will fix `videoData`.

Comment: thanks rmaddy it's working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting video File into `NSData`

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videopath];
```

or else video from url

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:VideoUrl];
```

Answer (score -1):

all you need to do is replace you code with this and it will work fine

```
 NSData *dataVideo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F5A89447-0720-4956-BD83-EEB541EE69AC/tmp/capture-T0x146e04ad0.tmp.TnQgmW/capturedvideo.MOV"];
```